# Spring boot annotations @springbootapplication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-security

> Can I create more than one application class with @springbootApplicatio annotations in our project.
>     Or a projects has Only one application class.

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation) on what `@SpringBootApplication` does for your application. From that you can understand that this annotation is a shortcut to simplify the use of a few other annotations. Those other annotations are more flexible and allow you to configure more options than `@SpringBootApplication`.